# Problem of background-color with bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

as mentionned in the title, I have a problem with a navbar. I can't change the background-color and his opacity with rgba, so please if you have an idea, can you help me ?

```css
#navbarr {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md" id='navbarr' role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only" id="asupr">Toggle navigation</span>
        &#x2630;</button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="active nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="works.html" class="smoothscroll nav-link">Travaux</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="smoothscroll nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove  bg-dark class.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md" id='navbarr' role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only" id="asupr">Toggle navigation</span>
        &#x2630;</button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Portfolio</a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="active nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="works.html" class="smoothscroll nav-link">Travaux</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="smoothscroll nav-link">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```